# Can I use facebook version 4.23 in android os 4.0(kitkat) api 14?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.x

I'm just using facebook sdk for sign in.
Can I use facebook 4.23 version or lastest version for android api 14?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do so. Below is the official link for facebook sdk documentation.For further information please refer below link

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads
```